# How can I put a whole code block in spoiler text?

Tags: support, code-formatting, spoilers

How do you put a whole codeblock into spoiler text?

This is normal text

> This is spoiler text

`This is one line of visible code`

> `This is one line of invisible code`

```
def visible_function():
  print 'hello world'
```

But to get a multi-line code block that is invisible?

```
def invisible_function():
  print 'Eeek! I feel so naked!'
```

Comment: This still does not seem to be possible, on SO at least, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112305/code-samples-inside-of-spoilers-are-still-visible-on-some-sites does not seem to have been resolved. I'd love to be able to give answers on SO using [this technique from Math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11636/90044).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do it using HTML

```
>! <pre><code>def invisible_function():
>!   print 'Eeek! I feel so naked!'</code></pre>
```

This results in some extra padding, though.

> ```
> def invisible_function():
>    print 'Eeek! I feel so naked!'
> ```

Comment: I [tried your approach on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723010/hover-state-remains-until-something-else-is-hovered/9724002#9724002) but it didn't work:-(

Comment: Doesn't work on math.SX, either.

Comment: @Christoph: It looks like the CSS for spoilers conflicts with the syntax highlighting (which is disabled here).

Comment: @Christoph, there's a bug report for that: [Code samples inside of spoilers are still visible on some sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112305/code-samples-inside-of-spoilers-are-still-visible-on-some-sites).

Comment: This does not work if you use `<>` in the code, e.g. `<pre><code>#include <stdio.h></pre></code>` or `<pre><code><i>text</i></code></pre>`

Comment: @ace: You can use `&lt;` and `&gt;` to escape them.

Comment: this worked for me in Anime.Stackexchange here https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27603/why-didnt-anyone-in-the-school-notice-that-natsume-is-actually-a-female

Answer (score 9):

This may not be the right way to do this. I was just trying different combinations with the syntax and came up with one possible way to include multiline code within the spoiler section using the HTML `<pre>` tag.

By default, the text is not shown as per spoiler behavior.

[image: text hidden]

Multiline code displayed onmouseover.

[image: multiline code]

**`Example`**

> ```
> SELECT  *
> FROM  dbo.Spoiler
> WHERE NumberOfLines > 1
> ```