# Code samples inside of spoilers are still visible on some sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, spoilers

Code samples (using the backtick) inside of spoilers are still visible. [Like](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3878/playing-the-name-game/3881#3881) shown in this screen capture:

[image: Code fragment visible in spoiler text]

It does this on most sites other than SO and Meta.

As you can see below, code is still invisible inside of spoilers here on meta.

> - Spoilers are denoted by the `>! string` before the line that is being spoiled.

Having bits of a spoiler visible before you mouse over it kind of spoils the purpose of a spoiler.

Comment: Oops, my bad: I voted to close too, but when I was about to change "visible" into "not visible" in the title, I realized I totally misread this. Enhanced the post a bit. I think it's **NOT a duplicate,** @Michael et al!

Comment: @Arjan They seem the same; the post I linked to is "how do I make code in a spoiler block invisible", this is "bug: code in a spoiler block is visible"

Comment: I disagree, @Michael. This one is about the backticks erroneously being visible (which actually matches the 2nd example in the other post, which renders fine, in Meta's color scheme). Just a minor CSS tweak to fix this, I guess.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek No. On the other question, he made inline code invisible in his spoiler. I'm saying that on some sites, inline code is visible inside of spoilers. His problem was specific to block code, this is specific to inline code.

Comment: While waiting for a proper fix from the SE folks, I've included a client-side fix for this ([and a bunch of other spoiler CSS issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217779/the-css-for-spoilers-is-a-mess-lets-fix-it)) in [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.6.

Comment: I'd love to see this resolved, there is a [great technique for posting answers](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11636/90044) on Math that I'd love to be able to easily apply on SO.

Comment: Looks like this got fixed somewhere down the line.

Answer (score 4):

Also, prettified code *blocks* are visible, even on SO and here on Meta. I'd have guessed this was not an issue for anyone, but [apparently it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723010/hover-state-remains-until-something-else-is-hovered/9724002#9724002).

In spoilers, using `<pre>` works, but using `<pre><code>` [currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bsVK.png) messes up with hiding the spoiler:

- Code is always visible (and goes all black on hovering).
- Text after the code block is even invisible on hover in a regular browser (select the text below to see more), or printed [within the "Click to show spolier" text on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQKhB.png).

> Spoiler with a code block:
>
> ```js
>  var a = 3;
>  while (not (a > 0)) {
>    alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
>  }
> ```
>
> (Also, the paragraph spacing is very different from regular Markdown.)

Even `<!-- language-all: none -->` does not fix this, as then all text is just rendered in black once Prettify kicks in:

> Spoiler with a code block:
>
> ```
>  var a = 3;
>  while (not (a > 0)) {
>    alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
>  }
> ```
>
> (Also, the paragraph spacing is very different from regular Markdown.)

Comment: We have never really supported mixing HTML and Markdown in the same post. Don't use the `<pre>` and `<code>` *tags* inside spoilers, and you're pretty much all set.

Comment: Unfortunately, spoilers don't support Markdown code blocks, @Anna. (Not that I ever use spoilers, and even if I did I'd dislike the huge blank grey block... For that, I'd still recommend [re-using the spoilers from the mobile theme on regular sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138952/use-spoilers-from-mobile-theme-on-regular-sites-too), but like noted above, the mobile layout messes up the above as well.)