# Consecutive spoiler blocks (>!) are shown as blockquotes

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, spoilers

The markdown

```
>! a

>! b

>! c
```

Will be shown as a blockquote with `!` in front of it:

> a

> b

> c

Instead of a spoiler for 3 paragraphs (or 3 spoiler blocks, whatever).

Comment: Related: [Paragraphs breaks are ignored inside spoilers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112793), [How can I put a whole code block in spoiler text?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105735), [Spoilers don't format well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116613), [What's the exact syntax for spoiler markup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72877) - This looks [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. Nowhere in Kevin's official response to this does he mention paragraph support. He specifically uses two spaces to create line breaks, in fact.

Comment: @animuson: I'd argue that's not an exact duplicate, because the one in http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112793 is about `>! abc` ↵ `>!` ↵ `>! def`, but mine is about `>! abc` ↵ ↵ `>! def`. The output is also different, the one in http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112793 is still a spoiler, but here is a blockquote.

Comment: It's still the same issue.Paragraphs are being ignored. You're just attempting to use paragraphs in a different way. Since spoilers just plain don't look for paragraphs, the two different ways result in two different outputs, but it's still the same underlying issue.

Comment: @Grace any idea why Oded deleted the dupe? No comment, and it looks like a valid report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Lack of attention and also the fact it's not fully classified a bug as much. Plus possible changes  in some unknown time in the future may change how this all works... so a fairly unmaintained and invisible post seemed, at the time, an acceptable casualty in the NAME OF PROGRESS.

Comment: @Grace so 99% of the bug reports should be deleted in such a case :(

Comment: @Shadow Usually they do get cleaned up when resolved. It's a matter of usefulness to keep around - something that we have to point at repeatedly because it keeps getting asked, for example, wouldn't get deleted. A post that hadn't been even looked at since 2012, that was of little information anyway? Oded didn't know it was a dupe target, so absent that data, it's a stagnant report on something that no one was maintaining, neither in interest nor in direction. With the option of maintaining something that's veritably invisible versus just clearing it out as better things are coming...

Comment: Can we add these workarounds to the documentation (https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help/#spoilers) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) as a result of the migration to CommonMark.

Basically, the prior renderer had an ambiguity in its specification. Essentially, block quote markup on separate lines would be combined into a single block quote when rendered, but *spoilers* were not to be combined. So the following markup:

```
>! test

>! test

>! test
```

...could be interpreted in two different ways: either it's a single block quote on three separate lines to be merged, with the exclamation point part of the lines, or as three separate spoiler blocks. It seems the previous renderer went with the former interpretation, causing the bug here.

However, as of the transition to CommonMark that happened earlier this year, the renderer specification has changed: block quotes on separate lines were not to be combined, but instead treated as separate blocks of text on their own. As such, the former interpretation above became invalid, and so the system now uses the latter (correct) interpretation.

In order to show the previous buggy behavior, it is now necessary to put a single angle bracket on all the empty lines:

```
>! test
>
>! test
>
>! test
```

Without those, those are treated as separate blocks of text, and are (correctly) recognized as spoilers.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly simple workaround to this:

```
>! a

<!-->
>! b

<!-->
>! c
```

Results in

> a

> b

> c

If you want to space them out a bit more, you can use `&nbsp;` instead of `<!-->`, but I'm guessing you don't want a bunch of blank gaps just to keep the spoilers separate.

Comment: Thanks, but I knew there is workaround already. (I used `# ` instead of `<!-->`)

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround, resulting in "whole" spoiler block without gaps:

> a
>  b
>  c

Achieved with:

```
>! a  
>! b  
>! c
```

The trick is having two spaces in the end of each  line, hence adding a line break.

Another option:

```
>! a<br />
>! b<br />
>! c
```

For those who feel more comfortable with HTML than with spaces.

Comment: We appreciate the answer, but this is documented in the original information about how to use MarkDown in general and Spoilers specifically: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396/282094 linked from: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72878/282094