# Multiline spoiler tags break with spaces between them

Tags: bug, markdown, spoilers

> ! If you have a multiline spoiler, you get a post that looks like this.
>
> ! The spoiler tag does not work and breaks on a line break. Neither spoiler works and it immediately converts to a normal "quote."

The expected behavior would be similar to a multiline quote:

> Hello
>
> World

except the entire block being converted to a spoiler.

---

The following also behaves... weird:

> > Line 1
>
> ! Line 2

Converting it to:

> > ! Line 1
> >
> > ! Line 2

Also causes more unexpected behavior (but more expected than the previous example).

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144824/)

Comment: @DanielFischer actually an exact dupe.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced this also, and the workaround I found is just insert `>!`   in the empty newline and add    to the first line.

```
>! If you have a multiline spoiler, you get a post that looks like this.
>!
>! The spoiler tag does not work and breaks on a line break. Neither spoiler works and it immediately converts to a normal "quote."
```

> If you have a multiline spoiler, you get a post that looks like this.
>
>  The spoiler tag does not work and breaks on a line break. Neither spoiler works and it immediately converts to a normal "quote."

(and yes, it's a bug but it's workaroundable)

Comment: This is an ok work around I guess. Be nice if this bug just was fixed, though..