# Please document that Spoilers don't work (or fix 'em)?

Tags: bug, markdown, spoilers

Isn't it pretty simple to edit the text at

https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help/#spoilers to document in the right place the problems pointed out again and again, e.g. [Consecutive spoiler blocks (>!) are shown as blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144824/consecutive-spoiler-blocks-are-shown-as-blockquotes) , [Spoilers don't format well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/spoilers-dont-format-well) etc.

> a simply by adding a link to one of them?

> b

> c

Tripped me up.

> d