# Using formatted code inside spoiler block?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I put a whole code block in spoiler text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105735/how-can-i-put-a-whole-code-block-in-spoiler-text)

I know I can use the `<code>` tag and some other html tags inside a spoiler block, but the code is not formatted or highlighted.

Is there a way to include formatted code inside a spoiler block?

Comment: In the preview, using `>! <code><pre> ...` actually *does* trigger highlighting, and then even messes up the spoiler, by *always* showing the text... (Assuming the question's tags would trigger some highlighting to start with.)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, everything in the spoiler block is treated as one paragraph. :-(

You cannot use bullets either. I consider this a bug, the parser should treat it just like a blockquote, albeit one that is rendered with an extra class. In a blockquote you can use all the other formatting options still, provided you use one extra space in your indentations:

> Block quotes support bullets and code blocks:
>
> - This is a bullet *with* a codeblock:
>
>   ```
>   # Python easter egg:
>   import this
>   ```

(note that no highlighting is applied to blockquotes either).

In a spoiler block (which only adds a `!` exclamation mark) this doesn't work, but I feel it should:

> Block quotes support bullets and code blocks:
>
>  * This is a bullet *with* a codeblock:
>
>          # Python easter egg:
>          import this

Your only workaround is to use explicit HTML tags yourself.

Markdown source for the above blocks are:

- Blockquote

  ```
  > Block quotes support bullets and code blocks:
  >
  > * This is a bullet *with* a codeblock:
  >
  >         # Python easter egg:
  >         import this
  ```
- Spoiler block

  ```
  >! Block quotes support bullets and code blocks:
  >!
  >! * This is a bullet *with* a codeblock:
  >!
  >!         # Python easter egg:
  >!         import this
  ```

Comment: Well, like the question explains: one *can* use HTML in spoilers, including lists.

Comment: @Arjan: Yup, but the spoiler block *should* be handled just like a blockquote instead.